# html+php+database (very beginner)

Tags: php, html, sql, database, postgresql

I'd like to ask for help about my code. I'm still beginning to find way with html, php, databases and all that. This is something I already did some times, but somehow I got stuck at this point.

The connection is fine, so I omitted it.

The thing is that my buttons don't do anything when I click them, it's like there's no action to be taken. At this point I can't notice my mistake, but I'm sure it's very simple. :(

- I've translated some things from the code from my native language to English, so if you find it inconsistent in that regard, I'm sorry. *

**I'd guess it's something I've messed up on the table structure**

Thank you!

```
<?php

    echo "<th>City |</th>";
    echo "<th>Update |</th>";
    echo "<th>Delete |</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $query = "SELECT name, id_city as id FROM city";
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query);

    if($result) {
        while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo $row['name'];
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<form method="post" action="./updatecity.php">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name=id_city value="'.$row['id'].'">';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<form method="post" action="./deletecity.php">';
            echo '<input type="hidden" name=id_city value="'.$row['id'].'">';
            echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete">';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }

    pg_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: You mean to say, that the form is not getting submitted ?

Comment: Actually not sure if that matters, but remove the `./` from the `action="./deletecity.php"` attribute...

Comment: First you have to find out _what_ is wrong. So use your browsers development console to learn about the request performed by the browser, take a look into your http servers error log file to find issues and start debugging by logging the contents of the `$_POST` superglobal variable in the server side.

Comment: thank you guys for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach to making form is completely wrong, what you are doing in simply echoing texts, No form is getting generated. Hence the button is not working because there is no button.

What you need to do it something like this :

```
<?php
  #Write your php related code here 
  #Like connecting to database
?>

#All your html related content goes here like making tables
<form method="post" action="./updatecity.php">
   <input type="hidden" name=id_city value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
</form>

<?php
 //Write your php related code here
?>
```

Comment: if the answer helped you could you accept it. So that others can get help.